# Laravel + Facebook PHP SDK rerequest declined permissions not working

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using [SammyK's laravel Facebook SDK PHP](https://github.com/SammyK/LaravelFacebookSdk) and I notice that the `auth_type=rerequest` is not working. This should happen when user declined one of the permission. Let's say I have `'default_scope' => ['email', 'user_status', 'user_website']`, when user un-ticks the email on the permission response the email will have a status of "declined".

```
"permission" => "email"
"status" => "declined"
```

But as stated on [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#reaskperms):

> It's OK to ask a person once to grant your app permissions that they've declined. You should have a screen of education on why you think they should grant the permission to you and then re-ask. But if you invoke the Login Dialog as before, it won't ask for that permission.
>
> This is because once someone has declined a permission, the Login Dialog will not re-ask them for it unless you explicitly tell the dialog you're re-asking for a declined permission.
>
> You do this by adding the auth_type=rerequest parameter to your Login Dialog URL:

So to do that in SammyK's service:

```
$fb = App::make('SammyK\LaravelFacebookSdk\LaravelFacebookSdk');
$loginFacebook = $fb->getReRequestUrl([]); // leave it to blank to get default scope from config
```

Having that, my login url looks like this now:
`https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?auth_type=rerequest&client_id={client_id}&state={state}&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.local%2Fdater%2Flogin%2Fcallback&scope=email%2Cuser_status%2Cuser_website`

Notice on the url that I have the `auth_type=rerequest` being passed on. (Do not mind the other parameters such as client_id and state, I just changed it here to make it shorter).

When I untick email, shouldn't it redirect back to the permission page? Because currently, it is still accepting it which makes the email scope declined and the app being accepted.

Comment: _“When I untick email, shouldn't it redirect back to the permission page?”_ – redirecting there is probably your responsibility (I don’t know that SammyK thing), after you checked and realized that one of the permissions you need was not granted. But you should not do that redirect immediately, but first explain to the user why your app needs that permission, and that it is going to ask for it again – probably best to not do an automatic redirect at all, but let the user trigger it by clicking a link/button.

Comment: And also be aware, that not every user does even _have_ an email address on file with Facebook, f.e. when they signed up using their mobile. If your app needs an email, and you don’t want to exclude those users, then you need to provide them with a form to enter their email address manually (and if you need it to be confirmed, you need to handle that as well then.)